# Is it possible to open 2 different instances of Chrome with different tabs open?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, tabs

I want to be able to open Chrome on my Mac, and have 2 instances open, each with different tabs.

Is this possible on OS X?

I know on Windows I could do this with Desktop shortcuts.

Comment: Why You need 2 instances? Can't You have 2 windows open (⌘+N)?

Comment: But I want them separated. E.G When I start up, I want 5 tabs open on 1 instance, and 3 different ones on another. I.E For 2 different screens.

Comment: That's exactly what separate windows are for. I have two windows open with different tabs. I close Chrome and reopen it and widnows are back to previous state.

Comment: Likely not. You can probably create a copy of Chrome called say "FrenchiesChrome" and open that instead of Chrome, but once running, it will have the process name Chrome, and use the apple.com.chrome.plist preferences file. Those realities are bound to get you into trouble when you also try to open the original Chrome App.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open new windows as separate application instances for Chrome, Terminal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230390/how-to-open-new-windows-as-separate-application-instances-for-chrome-terminal)

Comment: Clarification: new windows in Chrome are not the same thing as running a new Chrome application process.  Reasons you might want another Chrome process include wanting to be logged in to the same web site as two different users, or similar things.  Reasons you might encounter pain include sharing cookies and other client-side user data - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/277629/37037 for a solution to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need two separate instances of Chrome in order to have two windows. OS X works differently than Windows. To open new window in Chrome (or most of the other apps) press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>. Chrome restores window states after relaunch if You have this option enabled in preferences.

Comment: *"You do not need two separate instances of Chrome in order to have two windows. OS X works differently than Windows."* Actually, MS Windows works the same, you can have multiple/separate browser windows under a single instance.

Comment: I don't think someone who doesn't know CMD+N for the new window can find StackExchange ;)

Answer (score 5):

From the Terminal, you can run:

```
open -na "Google Chrome"
```

where `-n` parameters opens a new instance of the application.

Comment: That works for some apps, but Chrome seems to detect that there's already a running instance and it just gives you a new window in the running one.

Comment: problem is with command + tab. there is not possible switch user between chrome opened before in this commends and chrome make exactly the commend

Answer (score 5):

## On terminal,

/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --user-data-dir=/Users/***{UserName}***/Documents/Chrome-Personal

Of course, you can change the path you want.

### For convenient,

make a file in /Applications, named "chrome.command" with a TextEdit.app,

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --user-data-dir=/Users/{UserName}/Documents/Chrome-Personal
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to quit' &
exit
```

and type this on terminal,

```
sudo chmod 777 /Applications/chrome.command
```

type the system password if need.

And set the terminal preference like this,
[image]
Now, you got a second chrome when you click the file on the Finder.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the chrome icon in the tray of your desktop.  There will be an option to open new window select this.  Open the tabs in the new chrome window you want to have access to and right-click each of them to pin the tabs.