# Second instance of Mail.app possible?

Tags: macos, terminal, mail.app, command-line

I'd like to to start a second instance of Mail.app in macOS 10.14 for another email account.

I found this post about opening a new instance of Chrome: [How to open new windows as separate application instances for Chrome, Terminal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230390/how-to-open-new-windows-as-separate-application-instances-for-chrome-terminal)

and tried the Terminal commands but the catch is that they do open a second instance of Mail.app but also with the same account credentials that are already there. I want to start "from scratch" with the second instance and input whole different credentials.

There used to be a program "SwitchUp" a couple of years ago but it's not being developed anymore.

Anybody an idea if this is possible (without switching to another user account)?

Comment: Even if you find a way to run a second instance you still face the problem that Mail accounts/credentials are centrally managed in System Preferences. Might be easier to use a web mail interface for one of the accounts.

Comment: I think this is not [easily] possible using Mail, so you might be best served using another email client for the 2nd account. However, it is possible to manage several different email accounts within Mail, and keep them separate.

Comment: ok, I understand. Thank you for the input. I will stop searching for a solution now and consider webmail once more. I tried other clients but even if not perfect... I keep on coming back to Mail.app.

And I know, I can keep accounts separate (kind of) I would have simply loved to completely put them into different windows.

Comment: Why not just add multiple accounts to Mail app?

Comment: To separate private from business. Start one instance at a certain time, while the other is running all the time, clearer view on folder structures etc.